# HTML Code To Implement Collapsible Sections

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a popup.html file which presents the user with a slew of checkboxes.  There are major sections that I would like to create expand/collapse sections.  I am a neophyte web developer who knows enough to be dangerous.  I have spent the better part of the past 10 hours trying to modify my code to address this issue.  I have failed.  I would love some help.

Here is my current code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style type="text/css">
    div.top {
      width: 250px;
    }
    div.indent {
      margin-left: 20px;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<p>Select Games / Expansions / Assets:</p>
<div class="top">
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" id="g1" value="g1">
    <label for="g1">G1</label><br>
    <div class="indent">
      <input type="checkbox" id="g1-oc" value="g1-oc">
      <label for="g1-oc">G1 OC</label><br>
      <div class="indent">
        <input type="checkbox" id="g1-oc-x1" value="g1-oc-x1">
        <label for="g1-oc-x1">G1 OC X1</label><br>
        <div class="indent">
          <input type="checkbox" id="g1-oc-x1-a1" value="g1-oc-x1-a1">
          <label for="g1-oc-x1-a1">G1 OC X1 A1</label><br>
        </div>
        <div class="indent">
          <input type="checkbox" id="g1-oc-x1-a2" value="g1-oc-x1-a2">
          <label for="g1-oc-x1-a2">G1 OC X1 A2</label><br>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="indent">
        <input type="checkbox" id="g1-oc-x2" value="g1-oc-x2">
        <label for="g1-oc-x2">G1 OC X2</label><br>
        <div class="indent">
          <input type="checkbox" id="g1-oc-x2-a1" value="g1-oc-x2-a1">
          <label for="g1-oc-x2-a1">G1 OC X2 A1</label><br>
        </div>
        <div class="indent">
          <input type="checkbox" id="g1-oc-x2-a2" value="g1-oc-x2-a2">
          <label for="g1-oc-x2-a2">G1 OC X2 A2</label><br>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="indent">
      <input type="checkbox" id="g1-uc" value="g1-uc">
      <label for="g1-uc">G1 UC</label><br>
      <div class="indent">
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox" id="g1-uc-x1" value="g1-uc-x1">
          <label for="g1-uc-x1">G1 UC X1</label><br>
          <div class="indent">
            <input type="checkbox" id="g1-uc-x1-a1" value="g1-uc-x1-a1">
            <label for="g1-uc-x1-a1">G1 UC X1 A1</label><br>
          </div>
          <div class="indent">
            <input type="checkbox" id="g1-uc-x1-a2" value="g1-us-c1-a2">
            <label for="g1-us-c1-a2">G1 UC X1 A2</label><br>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox" id="g1-uc-x2" value="g1-uc-x2">
          <label for="g1-uc-x2">G1 UC X2</label><br>
          <div class="indent">
            <input type="checkbox" id="g1-uc-x2-a1" value="g1-uc-x2-a1">
            <label for="g1-uc-x2-a1">G1 UC X2 A1</label><br>
          </div>
          <div class="indent">
            <input type="checkbox" id="g1-uc-x2-a2" value="g1-uc-x2-a2">
            <label for="g1-uc-x2-a2">G1 UC X2 A2</label><br>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="popup.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

This code results in the following:

```
Select Games / Expansions / Assets:

[ ] G1
    [ ] G1 OC
        [ ] G1 OC X1
            [ ] G1 OC X1 A1
            [ ] G1 OC X1 A2
        [ ] G1 OC X2
            [ ] G1 OC X2 A1
            [ ] G1 OC X2 A2
    [ ] G1 UC
        [ ] G1 UC X1
            [ ] G1 UC X1 A1
            [ ] G1 UC X1 A2
        [ ] G1 UC X2
            [ ] G1 UC X2 A1
            [ ] G1 UC X2 A2
```

What I am trying to accomplish is have the code which will present the user collapsed sections as follows:

```
[ ] G1
```

When the user expands G1, they would see:

```
[ ] G1
    [ ] G1 OC
    [ ] G1 UC
```

If the user would expand G1 OC, they would see

```
[ ] G1
    [ ] G1 OC
        [ ] G1 OC X1
        [ ] G1 OC X2
```

If the user would expand G1 OC X1 they would see

```
[ ] G1
    [ ] G1 OC
        [ ] G1 OC X1
            [ ] G1 OC X1 A1
            [ ] G1 OC X1 A2
```

And so on.  Obviously, the functionality would have to expand and collapse the sections.  For now, I don't need a fancy caret, arrow, etc.  I could live with a simple "+" and "-" in front of each checkbox.

Ideally, the code would be self-contained without referencing outside resources.

I would appreciate any help I could get.  Hell, if someone could simply make one of the expansions/collapses to work, I am sure I could then modify the rest of the code to work in a similar fashion.  Thanks in advance for any help provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@any2cards It sounds like you're looking for [the `<details>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/details). Supported by all major browsers and requires no extra code.

```
<details>
  <summary>This content is visible at all times</summary>
  <p>This content is only visible when expanded</p>
</details>
```

Comment: Ryan, while this is indeed extremely elegant, and at first blush would seem to be the perfect solution, as it involves minimal code, it does NOT interact with my code and the checkboxes well at all.  If I place the summary around the labels with the major sections, it does make it expandable/collapsible, but the checkbox shows up above the line; then, the rest of the stuff below it does not flow well.  No matter where I place the details and the summaries, it doesn't work.  It's unfortunate, for it would be a concise solution.

Comment: Ryan, after much research, and working with my code, I was able to make the <details> <summary> suggestion you provided work.  This was definitely the most simplistic approach.  It has broken some of my JS that powers this popup, but I think I can resolve that.  Thank you for your great suggestion !

Answer (score 0):

made a REPL (interactive code thingymajig) where you can try the solution I'm going to explain to you here (commented as well): https://replit.com/@heyitsmarcus/Collapsing-Entries-CSS

First, I did have to replace the "UC" structure with the "OC" in what you copied and pasted because the "UC" structuring was broken. It still says UC because I just replaced OC references with UC.

One thing I added to the HTML was the class expando-controller to each checkbox that is responsible for expanding elements. I chose expando-controller because I liked it but you can choose whatever you like (just change the HTML classes and the associated CSS file)  The reason why I added this class was so that every checkbox had a common functionality that I can latch onto with JavaScript. Classes are powerful and, if utilized correctly, are one of the finest bits of HTML, CSS, and JavaScript.

Oh, and I swapped out the  attribute with a link to a CSS stylesheet. Try to avoid using those as you'll get some weird funkiness if you start using a blend of stylesheets and internal  tags. Best to avoid them if you can.

So, originally, I did this in JavaScript and posted a working but rather complicated answer...and deleted it. If you want to see that version, it is here: https://replit.com/@heyitsmarcus/Collapsing-Entries

You can add this functionality in just a few lines of extra CSS:

```
/* If an .expando-controller is checked, show its sibling .indent elements */
.expando-controller:checked ~ div.indent {
    display: block;
}

/* If an .expando-controller is not checked, hide its sibling .indent elements */
.expando-controller:not(:checked) ~ div.indent {
    display: none;
}
```

So long as you keep the same structure that you have, you can expand this ad infinitum.

Comment: Unfortunately, I wasn't clear enough.  You cannot leverage the checkboxes, because users will be using them to make selections.  What I want is something (like a button or whatever) that is to the left of each checkbox in the proper rows, that allows the user to click on it, to expand the appropriate sections, so that they THEN can click within specific checkboxes to select whatever they choose to select. In addition, I was really hoping that there was a solution that could be contained SOLELY within the HTML code (not requiring additional javascript files, CSS files, etc.

Comment: First of all, external CSS and JavaScript files are the right way to go.  You don't **need** to use additional files; however, as you get more experience with web development, you'll find   But, you can just add the above CSS to your `<style>` if your heart desires. And, a clever web developer can just give the `.expando-controller` class to a button instead of a checkbox.

Comment: Marcus, thank you for your efforts.  "Clever web developer" I am not.  I know enough to be dangerous.  I will take what you have provided, and see what I can come up with. Thanks.